# Imaging Windows HD with a OS X Disk Utility fails, "Invalid Argument"

Tags: macos, disk-utility, dmg-image

I have a Windows laptop HDD that I want to create an image file with, using OS X's Disk Utility.

When I try to create an image it fails (invalid argument). I created a [video of me attempting to create an image](http://youtu.be/aBt3wc-cqwo).

Anyone know how to fix this so that I can image this drive?

Comment: Can your mac write ntfs?

Comment: @Raystafarian I don't know how this would be connected. The image will be written to the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the specific error you're getting, but you can try to use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) and see if that works instead. Select your Windows volume as source on the left, and as destination, use *New Disk Image*.

In the settings, choose a read-only disk image.

[image]